# Omit intermediate types in function signature

Tags: scala, shapeless

I would like to perfom two maps over shapeless HList, I have folllowing code that works:

```
object doubleToInt extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseDouble = at[Double](_.toInt)
}


object intToDouble extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](_.toDouble)
}

def convert[InputType<:HList, ResultType<:HList, IntermediateType<:HList](input: InputType)(
  implicit mapper1: Mapper.Aux[doubleToInt.type , InputType, IntermediateType],
  mapper2: Mapper.Aux[intToDouble.type, IntermediateType, ResultType]
): ResultType = {
  input.map(doubleToInt).map(intToDouble)
}

convert(2.5 :: HNil)
```

as we can see the type of `convert` contains a type parameter `IntermediateType` that is completely irrelevant to the caller of this function. Is it posible to hide it somehow? It's a problem because I would like to call like this:

```
convert[SomeType, SomeType2, _](2.5 :: HNil)
```

but it doesn't compile because of unbound type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal solution when you want to infer only some type parameters of a method call is to split it into 2: the first fixes parameters you are interested in and returns a helper with `apply` method which is called to infer the rest. Applying this here, you'd get

```
def convert[ResultType <: HList] = new ConvertTo[ResultType]

class ConvertTo[ResultType <: HList] {
  def apply[InputType <: HList, IntermediateType <: HList](input: InputType)(implicit mapper1: Mapper.Aux[doubleToInt.type, InputType, IntermediateType],
  mapper2: Mapper.Aux[intToDouble.type, IntermediateType, ResultType]
) = input.map(doubleToInt).map(intToDouble)
}
```

Usage: `convertTo[SomeType].apply(2.5 :: HNil)`. `InputType` is inferred from `input` and then the compiler finds the implicit `mapper1` and infers `IntermediateType`.

Or at least, ideally it would: due to the way Scala type inference works, it can't infer `IntermediateType` from `mapper1` and then use it in `mapper2`, so I am not sure it'll find `mapper2` correctly. In future Scala versions this should be fixed by `def apply(implicit mapper1: ...)(implicit mapper2: ...)`, but the pull request enabling this [wasn't accepted in time for 2.12.0](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5108). If this turns out to be a problem, you'll have to split `ConvertTo.apply` in 2 again.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to hide implementation details of method operating on HList? If I would use 2x map, zip, fold, etc. all of them will leak out to the API(in form of type parameters and implicit evidences)?

Comment: At least, if there is such a way, I don't know it.

Comment: There may be some solution of this problem with existential types, but haven't check if it works yet.